# How to hold for loop iterations?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I want "Class A" to hold and not finish looping over all counts and wait for "Class B" to finish using the set of results coming out of "Class A". "Class B" is a wxPython dialog box which uses variables computed in "Class A" and do some calculations. But "Class A" finishes for loop and opens number of dialog boxes equal to for loop count altogether.

```
class A(object):
      count = 3
      for i in range(count):
          """do something"""
          dlg = B()

class B(object):
      """do something"""
```

How to hold it during each iteration of for loop to work with wxPython dialog box one-by-one?

Comment: use semaphore, that will lock A until B raises it. http://docs.python.org/2.3/lib/semaphore-examples.html

Comment: since he's talking about a GUI, using semaphores or other locking will probably be a bad idea here.  He needs to use something that returns control back to the GUI's main loop.  I've never used wxPython, but the GUI frameworks I have used all have a blocking dialog call like .run() that does this for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the dialog, you need to show it modally. This will cause the execution to "pause". So do something like this:

```
dlg.ShowModal()
```

That should work for your use case.